# How can set PFFILE into local UIImage in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uiimage, pfimageview

How can set local `UIImage to`PFFILE`

I haven't got image from parse database i have use uiimagepickercontroller

I have try to this code but not set image in `PFImageView`

```
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Group_icon.png"];
PFFile *file = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Image.jpg"  data:UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)];
[imageUser setFile:file];
[imageUser loadInBackground];
```

Please help me

Comment: Not a duplicate i have not set database only locally process in xcode

Comment: What is that your actually trying to accomplish. It may be a language barrier, or not, but your title and actual question seem far from similar. Are you trying to download an image stored on parse.com to your local device image view. Or the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this same issue. You can't use a PFFile in a PFImageView until it's been saved to the server and fetched. Probably something with how the caching works and using the url as key. The simple solution is to save it, then fetch it and set it on the imageview, but it's slow. The better solution is to keep the UIImage around, maybe in a NSCache or something, and use that until it's been saved to the server.